# Responsive NavBar Bootstrap with Mootools

Tags: mootools

I am trying to make a responsive navbar menu, just like the navbar of bootstrap but I can not use jquery, I am using Mootools. Have anyone done this behavior before?
Thanks.

Code:

Comment: Please add your code, its missing in the question. You could also checkout http://www.behaviorui.com/ which is basically Bootstrap + MooTools.

Comment: a responsive toolbar is framework agnostic. it's powered by CSS media queries and not JavaScript. Not using jQuery will cause issues with the JS components of BootStrap, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely provide more info, also Dimitar Christoff is right saying that responsiveness is powered by media queries.

But I can imagine your problem is actually to toggle the collapsed menu when clicking over the menu button, if this is the case I used to use this code, with mootools and bootstrap 3.

```
/* bootstrap */
window.addEvent('load', function() {
  $$('button[data-toggle=collapse]').each(function(btn) {
    var target = $(btn.get('data-target'));
    btn.addEvent('click', function() {
      target.toggle();
    })
  });
})
```